# How to set cell value on change of textbox value in excell sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Before asking here I did a lot of search on the net but could not get the solution. So I am writing it here.
My Sheet: 
[image]

I'm trying to set `Opening balance` value to the cell on `Change` event of the `Opening Balance`.
I tried to VBA too but not sure why it does not work for me.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code or work?

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far relative to your concern? Experts would be more willing to help if you can demonstrate your own effort on solving the problem.

Comment: @PaichengWu
Private Sub OpeningBalance_Change()
 MsgBox "texbox chenges" 
End Sub 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 
MsgBox "cell changes working"
 End Sub
 ================================================ 
Please get the excel from here expirebox.com/download/6e7e92b12e3b35e9dd338e79efadaa5e.html

Comment: @J.Mapz i looked for this-"how to set textbox value to  cell on change of textbox using vba"

Answer (score 0):

If your TextBox name is eg `TextBox1` then just use:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Range("A1").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Peh.
I tried to show a popup msg but its not working for text box change event.
However Worksheet selection change is working.

==============================================
Private Sub OpeningBalance_Change()
      MsgBox "texbox chenges"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox "cell changes working"
End Sub
================================================
Please get the excel from here
https://expirebox.com/download/6e7e92b12e3b35e9dd338e79efadaa5e.html

Comment: a) *"not working"* is a completely meaningless error description. b) `XLSX` files cannot contain any macros you must use `XLSM`. c) check your textbox name, I tested it and it works even with a msgbox.

Comment: @PEH i think you are not getting me.
Please download it
https://expirebox.com/download/0809d239be4306165e1c206ed1a2f38c.html
This is now a xlsm file and i tried to change the textbox named OpeningBalance that should show a pop up a "textbox Changes" mgs.. but it didnt.
why?

Comment: @GuaravKumar Ahhhh, now I see that you didn't use a TextBox at all! You must use the ActiveX-TextBox to make this work but you used a TextBox from the drawing tools, and that is the point here. • Change them into ActiveX TextBoxes: Read [How to use the forms controls on a worksheet in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291073/how-to-use-the-forms-controls-on-a-worksheet-in-excel) to show the Developer Tab and add a TextBox from Ribbon Tab Developer › Insert › ActiveX Controls › TextBox. With that TextBox it will work.

Comment: @peh Thanks .
This is what i was missing.
Thanks alot.